# Jquery Drop-down, change values inside the table and highcarts when drop-down triggered

Tags: jquery, json, highcharts

Im new to Jquery and highcharts.. So im posting this question on SO

I have a jquery drop-down which is multi-dependent. when the page is loaded, values(visitors today, yesterday and past week) under the "Asia" is displayed. and values changes based on the drop-down selected. This value is fetched to a text div. here is the jsfiddle `http://jsfiddle.net/binoymat/d9f8t9vj/17/`

HTML Code:

```
<select id="category"></select>
<select id="category1"></select>
<select id="category2"></select>
<select id="category3"></select>
<br>
<br>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-2 " id="services_block" style="width: 230px;height: 100px; background-color: orange;color: white; line-height: 30px; text-align: center; font-size: 100%;  font-weight: bold; border-left:3px solid white;
border-right:3px solid white;" >
Visitors 
<br> CURRENT DAY
<br>
<span id="totalVisitorsCurrentDay" style="color: black; font-size: 150%; font-weight: bold;" > </span>
</div>
<br>


<div class="col-sm-2" id="services_block" style="width: 180px;height: 100px;  background-color: red;color: white;line-height: 30px; text-align: center; font-  size: 100%;  font-weight: bold; border-left:3px solid white;
 border-right:3px solid white;">Visitors 
<br> PAST DAY
<br>
    <span id="totalVisitorsPastDay" style="color: black; font-size: 150%;  font-weight: bold;"></span>
    </div>
 <br>

<div class="col-sm-2" id="services_block" style="width: 180px;height: 100px;  background-color: red;color: white;line-height: 30px; text-align: center; font-size: 100%;  font-weight: bold; border-left:3px solid white;
border-right:3px solid white;">Visitors 
<br> PAST WEEK
<br>
    <span id="totalVisitorsPastWeek" style="color: black; font-size: 150%;  font-weight: bold;"></span>
    </div>



 </div>
 <br>
```

Jquery Code

```
$.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/2soxd", function (data) {
//code inside
var items = data;
var checkIds = [];
$.each(items, function (k, v) {
    if ($.inArray(v.id, checkIds) == -1) {
        $("#category").append('<option value="' + v.id + '" data-price="' + v.visitors + '">' + v.chains + '</option>');
        checkIds.push(v.id);
    }
});

$("#category").on('change', function () {
    var dept_number = parseInt($(this).val());
    var price = $(this).find(':selected').data('price');
    var tochange = false;
    var total = 0;
    var totalVisCurrDay= 0;
    var totalVisPasDay= 0;
    var totalVisPasWeek= 0;
    $.each(items, function (k, v) {
        if (v.id == dept_number) {
            if (tochange == true) {
                $("#category1").append('<option value="' + v.id + '" data-visitorscurrday="' + v.visitorscurrday + '" data-visitorspastday="' + v.visitorspastday + '" data-visitorspastweek="' + v.visitorspastweek + '" data-price="' + v.visitors + '">' + v.site + '</option>');
                $("#category2").append('<option value="' + v.id + '" data-visitorscurrday="' + v.visitorscurrday + '" data-visitorspastday="' + v.visitorspastday + '" data-visitorspastweek="' + v.visitorspastweek + '" data-price="' + v.visitors + '">' + v.zone + '</option>');
                $("#category3").append('<option value="' + v.id + '" data-visitorscurrday="' + v.visitorscurrday + '" data-visitorspastday="' + v.visitorspastday + '" data-visitorspastweek="' + v.visitorspastweek + '" data-price="' + v.visitors + '">' + v.date + '</option>');
            } else {
                $("#category1").html('<option value="' + v.id + '" data-visitorscurrday="' + v.visitorscurrday + '" data-visitorspastday="' + v.visitorspastday + '" data-visitorspastweek="' + v.visitorspastweek + '" data-price="' + v.visitors + '">' + v.site + '</option>');
                $("#category2").html('<option value="' + v.id + '" data-visitorscurrday="' + v.visitorscurrday + '" data-visitorspastday="' + v.visitorspastday + '" data-visitorspastweek="' + v.visitorspastweek + '" data-price="' + v.visitors + '">' + v.zone + '</option>');
                $("#category3").html('<option value="' + v.id + '" data-visitorscurrday="' + v.visitorscurrday + '" data-visitorspastday="' + v.visitorspastday + '" data-visitorspastweek="' + v.visitorspastweek + '" data-price="' + v.visitors + '">' + v.date + '</option>');
                tochange = true;
            }
            total += v.visitors;
            totalVisCurrDay += v.visitorscurrday;
            totalVisPasDay += v.visitorspastday;
            totalVisPasWeek += v.visitorspastweek;
        }
    });
    $('#dept-input').val(dept_number);
    $('#price-input').val(total);
    $("#totalVisitors").text(total);
    $("#totalVisitorsCurrentDay").text(totalVisCurrDay);
    $("#totalVisitorsPastDay").text(totalVisPasDay);
    $("#totalVisitorsPastWeek").text(totalVisPasWeek);
}).change();

$("select[id^='category']:not(#category)").on('change', function () {
    var dept_number = parseInt($(this).val());
    var price = $(this).find(':selected').data('price');
   var VisitorsCurrentDay = $(this).find(':selected').data('visitorscurrday');
  var VisitorsPastDay = $(this).find(':selected').data('visitorspastday');
  var VisitorsPastWeek = $(this).find(':selected').data('visitorspastweek');
    $('#dept-input').val(dept_number);
    $('#price-input').val(price);
    $("#totalVisitors").text(price);
   $("#totalVisitorsCurrentDay").text(VisitorsCurrentDay);
    $("#totalVisitorsPastDay").text(VisitorsPastDay);
    $("#totalVisitorsPastWeek").text(VisitorsPastWeek);
});
});
```

I want to know if its possible to create the following:-

a) when page is loaded, all values has to be displayed in the table like this, along with Highcharts

[desired output 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdk9y.png)

b) when any drop-down option is selected, table, value and highcharts should also change like this

[Desired Output 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKq1q.png)

Is this possible??? Pls edit the fiddle I posted if possible. thanks in advance

Comment: I suggest you read and understand first Highcharts' API Reference [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart).

Comment: @Tweetie Sabado I had gone through that.. Highcharts I have fectched successfully.. The problem what I am facing is this.. On click of the first drop-down, other drop-down(2nd, 3rd and 4th) values change, but the value in the table and highcharts do not change. what I mean is, when the page is loaded, table and Highcharts works fine.. when I click on drop-down(say 1st) Table should only show values(1st) of that particular option selected, and so must highchart...  this is what I am not able to fetch.. All values are still shown in the table and highchart.. doesn't change at all

Comment: @user5602805 You can change charts dynamically using e.g. [series.setData()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData). There is no chart in your fiddle, but you said that you added it and the problem is that it is not updating, so please post updated fiddle with chart.